# What does "her" refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In [Greyhound (2020)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greyhound_(film)), from Fletcher-class destroyer, Commander Ernest commands Taker
& Helmsman to intercept German U-boat, which was following 37 Allied ships,
which are making its way to Liverpool:

> Taker: Contact bearing 066, range indefinite, sir.
>
> Commander Ernest: Left hard rudder. Ease the rudder.
>
> Helmsman: Easing the turn. Aye, aye, sir.
>
> Commander Ernest: Meet **her**.
>
> Helmsman: Aye, aye, sir. Holding course.

What does "her" refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a naval tradition to refer to ships [as female](https://www.iwm.org.uk/history/why-do-ships-have-a-gender), so the commander is probably ordering the helmsman to meet - i.e. intercept - the U-boat they're pursuing.